# UIPageControl in UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I have a workspace with `MFSideMenu`. One voice of this menu has 3 `UIViewController` I would scroll with `UIpageControl`. it's possible?
How can it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basic example:

**In your app delegate**

```
#import "MFSideMenu.h"


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // Do other stuff

     MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = [MFSideMenuContainerViewController
                                                containerWithCenterViewController:centerViewController
                                                leftMenuViewController:leftMenuViewController
                                                rightMenuViewController:rightMenuViewController];
     self.window.rootViewController = container;
     [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

For more information:
https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu